# After an authenticated user closes my web app, how can I force them to reauthenticate with Azure B2C on reopening?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am using Azure B2C with local accounts in an ASP.NET core MVC web app, using the Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI to provide account controller (proof of concept), and using the recommended B2C_1_SignIn sign in flow.

If an authenticated user quits the web app (closes tab/browser) then reopens shortly after, they aren't forced to reauthenticate. I need that to happen.

Answer (score 0):

*Choose the Asp.net Core Web App as shown in the below snippet*

[image]

*And select the Authentication to Individual user accounts*

[image]

*Copy the application Id, Domain name
SignUp policy, reset password policy names from the azure polices of user flows screen.*

*then the App settings will be modified based on the data given.*

[image]

*In Azure we need to setup the Azure AD b2C Tenant and under Azure AD B2C and register your Asp.net core app using the default options*

[image]

[image]

*Configure the Authentication settings and  updating the redirection local app urls*

[image]

[image]

*Setting up authentication policies with user flows*

[image]

*The policies are created as shown below*

[image]

[image]

once the application is launched it will redirect to the login page

[image]

[image]

*Even after closing the app it will prompt to re-authenticate by Sign Option.
And you change the Authentication policies in users flow based on your requirement.*

*Refer this* [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/overview) *for more info*